# Directive accessing to parent controller function without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this directive that has its own scope but I want to access to a function inside its parent controller. I can do this if the parent controller exposes the function with a $scope.getElementsList(), although I'm trying to avoid the use of $scope and I have the function exposed with self.getElementsList() and the directive cannot reach it.

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('accountBalance', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
        elementId: '=elementid'
    },
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '../views_directives/account-balance.html',

    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.removeElement = function(){
            //this where I want to access the parent function
            console.log($scope.$parent.getElementsList());
            console.log("ALSO I WANT TO ACCESS THIS DIRECTIVE elementId WITHOUT USING $scope", $scope.elementId);
        }
    }
  };
});
```

ParentController:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppDesignCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.elementsList = [];
    self.getElementsList = function(){
        return self.elementsList;
    }

});
```

I also want to know what is the best way to access, inside the directive controller, the data passed to the directive's $scope.

```
scope: {
    elementId: '=elementid'
},
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-arrows element-drag"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-trash-o element-remove" ng-click="removeElement()"></i>
</div>
```

And what about calling functions from the directive template inside the controller of the directive? Do I need to expose them with something like $scope.removeElement()? How do I use this.removeElement() and be able to access it from the template?

Sorry about the long question. I'm trying to set the best practices to my new project since I've been away from angular for a year+.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? Things have changed considerably between 1.2 and 1.3.

Comment: How you are using your directive?

Comment: I'm using the latest release "version": "1.3.15" @NikosParaskevopoulos

Comment: <account-balance elementid="123123412"></account-balance> @Satpal

Comment: do you really need to 2 way bind the id in an isolated scope? If it was accessed as attribute the parent controller scope would be exposed inside directive

Comment: No. Not for now I guess. Could be @ instead.

Comment: my point was do you really need isolated scope?

Comment: Use case for isolated scope is specifically self-contained directive. If you need to share data with parent scope with ease, don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Going from bottom to top...)

To call functions in the controller without using the scope in Angular >= 1.2, use the `controllerAs` syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="AppDesignCtrl as appDesignCtrl">
    ...
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o element-remove" ng-click="appDesignCtrl.removeElement()"></i>
</div>
```

And `removeElement()` must be a method of the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppDesignCtrl', function ($scope) {
    ...
    this.removeElement = function() {
        ...
    };
});
```

To access the scope data from the controller in Angular >= 1.3, use the new `bindToController: true` configuration (this is especially useful when combined with the new `controllerAs` syntax):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('accountBalance', function() {
    return {
        ...
        scope: {
            elementId: '=elementid'
        },
        controller: function() {
            // now elementId is a member of the controller:
            console.log(this.elementId);
        }
    };
});
```

Having said these, the answer to how you can call `getElementsList` from the directive would be:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('accountBalance', function() {
    return {
        ...
        scope: {
            elementId: '=elementid',
            getElementList: '&'
        },
        controller: function() {
            ...
            // invoking the expression that was passed to us
            var theElements = this.getElementList();
        }
    };
});
```

The correct expression should be passed as:

```
<div ng-controller="AppDesignCtrl as appDesignCtrl">
    <account-balance element-id="xxx"
        get-elements-list="appDesignCtrl.getElementsList()"></account-balance>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked very well. My only question is about the access from the directive html template to the directive controller. 

Template URL of the directive:
<i class="fa fa-trash-o element-remove" ng-click="removeElement()"></i>
To the controller of the directive
angular.module('myApp').directive('accountBalance', function() {
     ...
    templateUrl: '../views_directives/account-balance.html',

    controller: function() {
        this.removeElement = function(){
         ...
        }
    }
  };
});
Since that controller doesn't have a name how can I use the controllerAs in that case?

Comment: I think you want the `controllerAs` directive configuration. Check it out in the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$compile), it works as `{ restrict: 'E', ..., controller: function()..., controllerAs: 'ctrl', ...}` and then the controller is available in the template of the directive as `ctrl`, e.g. to access the field foo of the controller, you write `{{ ctrl.foo }}` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not recommended, because directives are meant to be self-contained. It isn't critical if you don't plan to reuse the directive. And wise usage of isolate scope can solve this.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('accountBalance', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
        outerScope: '@'
        elementId: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '../views_directives/account-balance.html',

    controller: function($scope) {
        console.log("we can use anything from other controller", $scope.outerScope.elementsList)
        $scope.elementId = "and share data with any other scope";
    }
  };
});
```

Controller is defined as `ng-controller="AppDesignCtrl as appDesign"`, and directive usage is

```
<account-balance element-id="sharedParentScopeVar" outer-scope="appDesign">
```

So there won't be any problem if the directive should be moved to other controller.

I guess 'best practice' may be to set up a service that embraces the data and is used by both app controller and directive, so directive controller operates on data items and not DOM elements.

> And what about calling functions from the directive template inside
>   the controller of the directive? Do I need to expose them with
>   something like $scope.removeElement()?

You surely don't. If there's a need to use functions from outside, you're doing something wrong. Send a message to respective element to run the function if it is DOM-related. Or put the function into the service if it is data-related.